# Incorporating new data in classification

Tags: cart

I am trying to predict class membership (classification) and have a database of 40k observations (people) with 94 attributes.  I have also asked a thousand people from the database to fill in a more extensive survey and have 400 further attributes for them.

I don't want to waste the time of everyone on the database with filling in the entire survey.  I'd like to work out for each person what questions would give me a reasonable estimate of their class membership.  Essentially I want to build a decision tree for every person where the nodes in the decision tree are the questions to ask.

Because values for the 94 attributes will be different from person to person I would expect everyone's decision tree to be different, but because some questions are much more predictive of the class I would expect most trees to be similar.

Any help or pointers appreciated!